# Function Call happens before File Load?

Tags: canvas, processing

A document.ready jQuery function call runs before the Processing .pde file fully loads.. This results in an undefined error, as logged in the console.

Is there a way to preload the .pde, which is a nice 4kb, but load after 1.5 sec, when everything else loads before the .5sec marker..

By way of Processing though, the .pde file loads with the canvas tag:

```
<canvas id="canvasID" data-processing-sources="../canvasID.pde"></canvas>
```

So how would the `data-processing-sources` be loaded before that?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use [load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) against the window?

```
$(window).load(function() {
    // this should run after the whole page loads
});
```